# ¿Cómo convertir un objeto JSON a un Array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estoy intentando transformar un objeto JSON a un array de javascript, donde el arreglo consistiría de las llaves y valores en el objeto. Lo he hecho de diferentes maneras y no lo he logrado.

```
//Objeto Json
[
 {dato: 'asdasd'},
 {dato:'234234'}
]
```

El resultado deseado sería algo asi:

```
//Array 
[
 [dato, 'asdasd'],
 [dato, '234234']
]
```

He utilizado el `typeof` con diferentes métodos pero siempre el resultado de este es `object`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma sencilla podría ser iterarlo a través de sus llaves:

```js
var arreglo = [
    {dato: 'asdasd'},
    {dato:'234234'}
];

/**
 * Array.prototype.map(fn: callback) es un método que se ejecutará por
 * cada elemento dentro del arreglo sobre el cúal fue llamado.
 *
 * @see {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map}
 * @param {Object} o
 */
var nuevoArreglo = arreglo.map(function(o) {
    /**
     * Array.prototype.reduce(fn: callback, value: any) es un método que pasa un valor inicial
     * a cada iteración, el valor devuelto será pasado por cada iteración y devuelto como
     * resultado al final del bucle.
     *
     * @see {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce}
     * @param {Array} array  Con un valor inicial [].
     * @param {string} key   Llave del objeto.
     */
    return Object.keys(o).reduce(function(array, key) {
        return array.concat([key, o[key]]);
    }, []);
});

console.log(nuevoArreglo);
```

El resultado sería:

```
[
    ["dato", "asdasd"],
    ["dato", "234234"]
]
```

Comment: Genial funciono, ademas que la respuesta esta muy bien explicada muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Una opción sencilla es usar una combinación de: [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), y [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
const objetoJson = [
  { dato: 'asdasd' },
  { dato: '234234' },
];
const arr = objetoJson.map(elemento => Object.entries(elemento));

console.log(arr);
```

Con `objetoJson.map()` recorres cada elemento del array de objetos, devolviendo un valor por cada elemento del array. Con `Object.entries(elemento)`, obtienes un array con la clave y valor de cada elemento, así que ya tendrías lo que necesitas.